# Storing strings longer than a single word from an input txt file into two separate arrays

Tags: c++

This is a little bit of a repeated question because I thought I had enough of an answer to get where I needed. Turns out I did not. I have a .txt file that is formatted like so,

```
It is certain
positive
You may rely on it
positive
.
.
.
Very Doubtful
negative
```

I need to take this text file and separate it into two separate arrays one for the responses and one for the categories. So far I have been able to separate the .txt file into two strings using getline, but I can't seem to get it into an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int size = 20;
    int i = 0;
    string responses[size];
    string categories[size];
    string line1, line2;

    ifstream infile("responses.txt");
    if(infile.is_open())
    {
        //input
        while(getline(infile, line1) && getline(infile, line2))
        {
                //cout << line1 << endl;
                //cout << line2 << endl
                getline(infile, line1) >> responses[i];
                getline(infile, line2) >> categories[i];
                cout << responses[i] << endl;
                cout << categories[i] << endl;
                ++i;

        }

        infile.close();
    }else
        {
        cout << "File not open" << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have had several different iterations and changes of the code above but this was the most recent one. Thanks in advance for any help or guidance. It is much appreciated by this programming noob.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). I recommend either [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead. Though in this case, when you don't seem to be using the arrays after your loop, why use an array at all?

Comment: I have been working on this and after getting something that works I'll put it in a function that will be used elsewhere. Unfortunately it is for an assignment and we have to use an array, otherwise I would have just used a vector and been done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the size of these two arrays(number of lines in the responses.txt), try this

```
for(int i=0; i<size_array; i++){
    getline(infile, responses[i]);
    getline(infile, categories[i]);
}
```

`getline(infile, line1)` will get the current line in responses.txt into line1, you don't need to getline() again inside the while() code.

And if you don't know how many lines are in the responses.txt, consider using `std::vector` instead of a plain array.

```
std::vector<std::string> responses, categories;
while(getline(infile, line1) && getline(infile, line2)){
    responses.push_back(line1);
    categories.push_back(line2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The first bit worked perfectly since I do know number of lines in the text. I can't believe how long I worked on this to have completely overlooked that solution.